# .NET - Is it possible to proxy a HTTPS request using HttpListener & HttpWebRequest? (or is it not possbile due to the encryption?)

Tags: .net, ssl, proxy, https, httplistener

Question - Is it possible to proxy a HTTPS request using HttpListener & HttpWebRequest?  (or is it not possbile due to the encryption?)

I have got a .NET proxy working by using HttpListener & HttpWebRequest using the approach [here](http://www.jeffcrossman.com/2009/08/27/using-httplistener-to-build-a-proxy/). I'm trying to extend this at the moment to listen for HTTPS too ([refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619251/net-httplistener-when-registering-both-http-https-i-get-conflicts-with-an-ex)) however I'm wondering if I'm trying to tackle something that is not possible...That is if this code works by listening for the HTTPS request (using HttpListener) and then copying headers & content across to a new HttpWebRequest, is this flawed as it may not be able to decrypt the request to get the content?

But then normal proxy servers obviously can proxy HTTPS, so I guess perhaps it will work because it will just copy across the encrypted content?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not if the IP address is different. You could try implementing the X-Forwarded-For in the HTTP GET request, but I doubt that would work.

Comment: But the existing proxy servers (e.g. BIND) must be able to do it without terminating the HTTPS no?  I'll try to give X-Forwarded-For a go...

Comment: can't seem to verify this at the moment - I'm hitting the issue/question I've asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619251/net-httplistener-when-registering-both-http-https-i-get-conflicts-with-an-ex