# Why isn't my server accessible outside of my computer?

Tags: vb.net, httpserver

I've created a Http Server in VB.net.  I've used the same "template", I guess you could say, for every project requiring an Http Server (quite a few recently).  The problem is, this one I'm working with now requires that the computers on the LAN be able to connect to it.  I can access the server directly from my computer though using: `http://127.0.0.1:8002/`.  Here is my source code (skimmed down of course):

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class MainWindow

    Private Enum ApplicationSituation
        Idle
        Login
        TrackPage
    End Enum

    Private CurrentApplicationSituation As ApplicationSituation = ApplicationSituation.Idle

    Private listener As New HttpListener
    Private theService As String

    Private Const PORT As Integer = 8002
    Private Const SERVERNAME As String = "Poptimas"

    Private ContentTypes As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Private ServerThread As Threading.Thread

    Private Sub WriteContentTypes()
        '(TEXT) Human-readable text and source code
        ContentTypes.Add(".txt", "text/plain")
        ContentTypes.Add(".htm", "text/html")
        ContentTypes.Add(".html", "text/html")
        ContentTypes.Add(".xml", "text/xml")
        ContentTypes.Add(".css", "text/css")
        ContentTypes.Add(".csv", "text/scv")
        ContentTypes.Add(".htc", "text/x-component")
        ContentTypes.Add(".js", "application/javascript")
        '(IMAGE)
        ContentTypes.Add(".png", "image/png")
        ContentTypes.Add(".jpg", "image/jpg")
        ContentTypes.Add(".bmp", "image/bmp")
        ContentTypes.Add(".gif", "image/gif")
        ContentTypes.Add(".tiff", "image/tiff")
        ContentTypes.Add(".ico", "image/vnd.microsoft.icon")
        '(AUDIO)
        ContentTypes.Add(".mp3", "audio/mp3")
        ContentTypes.Add(".wav", "audio/vnd.wav")
        ContentTypes.Add(".ogg", "audio/ogg")
        ContentTypes.Add(".mwa", "audio/x-ms-wma")
        '(VIDEO)
        ContentTypes.Add(".mp4", "video/mp4")
        ContentTypes.Add(".wmv", "video/x-ms-wmv")
        ContentTypes.Add(".mov", "video/quicktime")
        '(APPLICATION) Non-standard
        ContentTypes.Add(".pdf", "application/pds")
        ContentTypes.Add(".swf", "aplication/x-shockwave-flash")
    End Sub

    Private Function ParseQuery(ByVal queryset As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim FinQu As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        If queryset.Length > 0 Then
            For Each qSet As String In queryset.Substring(1).Split("&")
                Dim sA() As String = qSet.Split("=")
                FinQu.Add(sA(0), sA(1))
            Next
        End If
        Return FinQu
    End Function

    Private Sub StartServer()
        Try
            Dim machineName As String = System.Environment.MachineName
            VariableValues.Add("port", PORT)
            VariableValues.Add("computer", machineName)
            theService = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SERVERNAME)

            WriteContentTypes()

            With listener
                .Prefixes.Add(String.Format("https://*:{0}/", PORT.ToString))
                .Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:" & PORT.ToString & "/")
                .Start()
            End With

            Dim context As HttpListenerContext
            Dim path As String


            While listener.IsListening
                context = listener.GetContext
                path = context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower
                Dim query As Dictionary(Of String, String) = ParseQuery(context.Request.Url.Query)
                If path = "/" Then
                    Select Case CurrentApplicationSituation
                        Case ApplicationSituation.Idle

                        Case ApplicationSituation.Login
                            SendPage(context.Response, My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "/MobilePandoraConnection/login.html", ".html")
                        Case ApplicationSituation.TrackPage
                            SendPage(context.Response, My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "/MobilePandoraConnection/track.html", ".html")
                    End Select
                ElseIf path = "/inject" Then
                    SendPage(context.Response, My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "/MobilePandoraConnection/PandoraMediaServer.js", ".js")
                Else
                    SendPage(context.Response, My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "/MobilePandoraConnection" & path, path.Substring(path.IndexOf(".")).ToLower())
                End If
            End While

            With listener
                .Stop()
                .Close()
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendPage(ByVal response As HttpListenerResponse, ByVal Location As String, ByVal extension As String)

        With response
            .ContentType = ContentTypes(extension)
            .ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8

            Try
                Dim cont() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(page)
                Else
                    cont = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(Location)
                End If
                .OutputStream.Write(cont, 0, cont.LongLength)
                .OutputStream.Flush()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Server Error: " & ex.ToString)
            Finally
                Try
                    .Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
            End Try
        End With

    End Sub

    Private Sub MainWindow_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        'Stupid Server likes to keep everything running - kill that sucka'
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SystemPanel_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        'Start server in new thread to prevent an un-reponsive form
        ServerThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf StartServer)
        ServerThread.Start()
    End Sub

End Class
```

If anything doesn't work (such as, if you tried to copy and paste it straight in for testing), I probably just made a mistake while I was taking some of the unessential code out.

**And by-the-way:**
 - My Firewall is not running

**EDIT FOR STEVEDOG**

I've made these the two prefixes:

```
.Prefixes.Add(String.Format("https://*:{0}/", PORT.ToString))
.Prefixes.Add(String.Format("http://*:{0}/", PORT.ToString))
```

Now I get an error every time when it tries to apply the prefixes:

> Failed to listen on prefix 'https://*:8002/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.

I've checked all the ports that are listening and 8002 is still open...

Comment: @SteveDog Good question.  No.  :)

Comment: Consider posting only relevant code in the future...

Comment: @pst It is all relevent.  I only posted the code for the server.  I was unsure as of which part was causing the problem so I posted all of the parts that COULD be posting the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `.Prefixes.Add(String.Format("http://*:{0}/", PORT.ToString))` instead of `.Prefixes.Add(String.Format("https://*:{0}/", PORT.ToString))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't listen on IP address 127.0.0.1.  You need to actually listen on your real IP address.  Listening on 127.0.0.1 will only receive messages that are sent specifically to the loop-back address.

Also, you can't listen to both http and https on the same port and IP address using the HttpListener.  See this link for more info:

[.NET HttpListener: when registering both HTTP & HTTPS I get "conflicts with an existing registration on the machine"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619251/net-httplistener-when-registering-both-http-https-i-get-conflicts-with-an-e)

Comment: I've straightforwardness it and it still doesn't work.  At the same time, I also run a commercial server on port 8001 on my local IP address and it works fine.  I've tried connecting to my computers server using `http://192.168.1.1:8002`.  The commercial server works fine, mine doesn't however.

Comment: So you changed the line `.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:" & PORT.ToString & "/")` to `.Prefixes.Add("http://192.168.1.1:" & PORT.ToString & "/")` and it still doesn't work?

Comment: @XanderLamkins Why do you have an asterisk on the https prefix, but not on the http prefix?  Did you try changing the http prefix to also use an asterisk instead of the specific IP address?  Have you tried using + instead of *?

Comment: 192.168.1.1 is a private address.  only computers on your local network can access that address.  It is NOT routed over the internet.

Comment: @RobertBeaubien He didn't say he was trying to access it over the internet, though that's a good point.  However, if that's his IP address, that's the IP address to listen on.  That's the one to use even for internet traffic.  It's up to the router to route those messages to that private IP address properly.  Which brings up a good point, if he is trying to do it over a router, he needs to make sure the router doesn't block that port and he needs to make sure everyone is accessing his computer via the router's public IP, not his private one.

Comment: @SteveDog, thanks for the help!  I just can't seem to get things to go right today.  +1 and a check for you :)

Answer (score 0):

In `http://127.0.0.1:8002/`, the address of your computer is `127.0.0.1`.

There are typically 4 ways to access your server :

- `127.0.0.1` : this will only work from your own computer.
- `192.168.1.1` or similar : this will work only on your local network. Because IPV4 addresses are very limited in number you're using addresses only valable on your LAN and don't have "permanent" IP addresses visible from everybody. Every computer on your LAN has a different local IP address but there are many computers in the world with the same local address.
- If your router between your LAN and Internet is configured to let enter connections coming from internet (which is a little dangerous for you especially if you have no firewall on your personal computer), then you have an IP that you may know using a lot of online services like http://www.knowmyip.com/. This address is temporary and will change at your next connection (because there aren't enough IPV4 addresses)
- a name, using a service like http://dyn.com/dns/ which offers to everybody a dynamic link between a constant name and your server. So that people can access your server using something like http://keods.dyndns.org instead of asking you what's your current IP address.

But as long as your server is on a private network without a fix IP address, your server will probably not be as easily accessed than a server hosted specifically by a dedicated company like http://www.ovh.co.uk/ (or another one, this is just an example). Before you give your address to your commercial partners, you should opt for one of the numerous naming and hosting offers, most of them being very cheap.